# How to add an attribute if input text field has some class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to add css atrribute to text field If it contains class. Here is my code :

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="masterTooltip" />
```

Here is my jquery script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type=text]').hasClass("masterTooltip").css( "title","Text Field");
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Just a question.Why don't you use id?

Comment: Why not just select by that class: `$('.masterTooltip')` ... ?

Comment: `title` is not css property.

Comment: css attribute or html attribute 'title'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want to add title attribute to an input which has a class you need to do something like this

```
$("input.masterTooltip").attr("title", "Text Field");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr()` instead of `css()`

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=text]', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("masterTooltip")) {
        $(this).attr( "title", "Text Field");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="masterTooltip" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns true, if found an element of this class or false, if element with this class not found, but not an element.

To select elements by class, do the following:

```
$('input[type=text] .masterTooltip')
```

Then, as you are not going to assign "Text Field" to css property named "title", but want to assign it to html attribute, using [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is incorrect in this case. You can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for this case:

```
$('input[type=text] .masterTooltip').attr("title","Text Field")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't use simply like this??

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=text].masterTooltip').attr( "title", "Text Field");
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymwswadg/1/)